# Mix Ide mac Crash on launch

Tags: ethereum

i have issues to install Mix, i updated everything and still have the same issue :

```
Process: Mix-ide [29364]
Path: /usr/local/Cellar/cpp-ethereum/1.2.4/Mix-ide.app/Contents/MacOS/Mix-ide
Identifier: .
Version: ??? (mix )
Code Type: X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process: ??? [1]
Responsible: Mix-ide [29364]
User ID: 501

Date/Time: 2016-05-03 16:09:56.394 +0200
OS Version: Mac OS X 10.11.4 (15E65)
Report Version: 11
Anonymous UUID: 13C99257-E029-CFC4-7857-A40E5D5F192E

Sleep/Wake UUID: 56AA9A03-8627-4D70-87F0-8D3C65C820CA

Time Awake Since Boot: 97000 seconds
Time Since Wake: 5700 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread: 3 QThread

Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: EXC_I386_GPFLT
Exception Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Thread 0:: CrBrowserMain Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0 libethereum.dylib 0x0000000113024880 0x112f4b000 + 891008
1 libethereum.dylib 0x0000000112fdeb9d dev::eth::ChainParams::genesisBlock() const + 1081
2 libethereum.dylib 0x0000000112f9264c dev::eth::BlockChain::genesis() const + 164
3 libethereum.dylib 0x0000000112f921db dev::eth::BlockChain::init(dev::eth::ChainParams const&, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&) + 171
4 libethereum.dylib 0x0000000112f91e9f dev::eth::BlockChain::BlockChain(dev::eth::ChainParams const&, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, dev::WithExisting, std::__1::function const&) + 979
5 . 0x000000010d03afbd dev::mix::MixBlockChain::MixBlockChain(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, std::__1::unordered_mapdev::FixedHash<20u, dev::eth::Account, std::__1::hashdev::FixedHash<20u >, std::__1::equal_todev::FixedHash<20u >, std::__1::allocatorstd::__1::pair<dev::FixedHash<20u const, dev::eth::Account> > > const&) + 99
6 . 0x000000010d03b864 dev::mix::MixClient::resetState(std::__1::unordered_mapdev::FixedHash<20u, dev::eth::Account, std::__1::hashdev::FixedHash<20u >, std::__1::equal_todev::FixedHash<20u >, std::__1::allocatorstd::__1::pair<dev::FixedHash<20u const, dev::eth::Account> > > const&, dev::SecureFixedHash<32u> const&) + 490
7 . 0x000000010d03b51c dev::mix::MixClient::MixClient(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&) + 300
8 . 0x000000010cfd96da dev::mix::ClientModel::init(QString) + 446
9 . 0x000000010d073cc8 0x10cfcc000 + 687304
10 . 0x000000010d074aea dev::mix::ClientModel::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void) + 112
11 org.qt-project.QtQml 0x00000001123c540b 0x112248000 + 1561611
12 org.qt-project.QtQml 0x00000001123c3ec0 0x112248000 + 1556160
13 org.qt-project.QtQml 0x00000001123c326b QV4::QObjectMethod::callInternal(QV4::CallData) const + 1099
14 org.qt-project.QtQml 0x00000001123d8656 QV4::Runtime::callProperty(QV4::ExecutionEngine, int, QV4::CallData) + 1206
15 ??? 0x0000000118c5af7e 0 + 4710575998
16 org.qt-project.QtQml 0x000000011236fb59 0x112248000 + 1211225
17 org.qt-project.QtQml 0x0000000112467894 QQmlJavaScriptExpression::evaluate(QV4::CallData, bool*) + 644
18 org.qt-project.QtQml 0x000000011240e26d QQmlBoundSignalExpression::evaluate(void) + 829
19 org.qt-project.QtQml 0x000000011240e975 0x112248000 + 1862005
20 org.qt-project.QtQml 0x00000001124482f5 QQmlNotifier::emitNotify(QQmlNotifierEndpoint, void) + 741
21 org.qt-project.QtCore 0x00000001129891a7 QMetaObject::activate(QObject, int, int, void) + 199
22 org.qt-project.QtQml 0x000000011247d5fd 0x112248000 + 2315773
23 org.qt-project.QtQml 0x0000000112404049 QQmlComponentPrivate::complete(QQmlEnginePrivate, QQmlComponentPrivate::ConstructionState) + 73
24 org.qt-project.QtQml 0x0000000112402269 QQmlComponentPrivate::completeCreate() + 41
25 org.qt-project.QtQml 0x0000000112403a22 QQmlComponent::create(QQmlContext) + 114
26 org.qt-project.QtQml 0x000000011246fcbf QQmlApplicationEnginePrivate::_q_finishLoad(QObject) + 111
27 org.qt-project.QtQml 0x0000000112470292 QQmlApplicationEngine::load(QUrl const&) + 34
28 . 0x000000010d033cb1 dev::mix::MixApplication::MixApplication(int&, char) + 115
29 . 0x000000010d033789 main + 42
30 libdyld.dylib 0x00007fff91fe15ad start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff97dfdefa kevent_qos + 10
1 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff930df165 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 216
2 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff930dedcd _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:: QQmlThread
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff97dfd07a __select + 10
1 org.qt-project.QtCore 0x00000001129aaf43 qt_safe_select(int, fd_set, fd_set, fd_set, timespec const) + 547
2 org.qt-project.QtCore 0x00000001129abe75 QEventDispatcherUNIXPrivate::doSelect(QFlagsQEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag, timespec*) + 709
3 org.qt-project.QtCore 0x00000001129ad2b7 QEventDispatcherUNIX::processEvents(QFlagsQEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag) + 231
4 org.qt-project.QtCore 0x000000011294ffe5 QEventLoop::exec(QFlagsQEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag) + 421
5 org.qt-project.QtCore 0x000000011278a843 QThread::exec() + 115
6 org.qt-project.QtQml 0x0000000112481e89 0x112248000 + 2334345
7 org.qt-project.QtCore 0x000000011278e2fa 0x112765000 + 168698
8 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff9979199d _pthread_body + 131
9 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff9979191a _pthread_start + 168
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff9978f351 thread_start + 13
```

the whole error below :

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/louisCharpentier/7f1348f6e1ae234814d9b31d426341dd.js"></script>
```

i ve already uninstall and re install, nothing as worked so far.
if you have any answer, thank you